# java web app calling a web service client (in cxf)

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications

I need a very performant and scalable solution to calling web services from java webapp.

Could someone please suggest the best options for calling webservices from java webapp?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a restful web service, there are a lot of client libraries which you can choose. Eg. RestEasy Client, Jersey Client,....